# Delete multiple asp.net repeater Items with checkbox selection only

Tags: c#, asp.net

here it does not show any error only page loading what is the error?

C# code

```
protected void imgs_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)  
        {        
            foreach (RepeaterItem ri in repeater.Items)
            {

            CheckBox item_check = (CheckBox)ri.FindControl("item_check");
            Label txt_id = (Label)ri.FindControl("txt_id");

                if (item_check.Checked)
                {
                    con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ram", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "DELETE");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", txt_id);
                    repeat();
               }                
        }     
}
```

asp.code

Comment: Please check http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bulk-delete-multiple-rows-in-ASPNet-Gridview-control-using-CheckBoxes.aspx

Comment: put it in a try catch block and print out the error in the catch block to see if really no errors are made

Answer (score 1):

You Forgot To Write `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

1. Stop Using `AddWithValue`
2. Always use `using` for `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` which implements `IDisposable`

   protected void imgs_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
           {

   ```
       foreach (RepeaterItem ri in repeater.Items)
       {

       CheckBox item_check = (CheckBox)ri.FindControl("item_check");
       Label txt_id = (Label)ri.FindControl("txt_id");

           if (item_check.Checked)
           {
         Using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon))
               {
         Using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ram", con))
                {
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
               con.Open();
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@Action",SqlDbType.Varchar,50).Value="DELETE";
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@eid",SqlDbType.Int).Value=Convert.ToInt16(txt_id.Text);
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              repeat();
               }
              }
          }                
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: i m getting this error Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach (RepeaterItem ri in repeater.Items)
    {

        CheckBox item_check = (CheckBox)ri.FindControl("item_check");
        Label txt_id = (Label)ri.FindControl("txt_id");

        if (item_check.Checked)
        {

            con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            cmd = new SqlCommand("ram", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "DELETE");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", txt_id.Text);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {

                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    repeat();
```